# Contextual type inference for Type in Swift 2.2+

Tags: swift, generics, types

I want to use first order citizen Type in Swift to decide which function to call.

```
func sf(v: [Float]) -> Float{
}

func  df(v: [Double]) -> Double {
}

func f<T: RealType>(seq ls: [T]) -> T {
  if T.self == Float.self {
    return sf(ls) // 1. where sf: Float -> Void
  } else if T.self == Double.self {
    return df(ls) // 2. where df : Double -> Void
  }
}
```

The type inference system couldn't notice that under one branch T == Float and Double in the other ?

Is here a missing feature, complex feature or bug ?

**Edit**:

```
typealias RealType = protocol<FloatingPointType, Hashable, Equatable, Comparable, FloatLiteralConvertible, SignedNumberType>
```

for my prototype but will become a protocol

Comment: How's `RealType` defined in your code?

Comment: RealType is a typealias for now. I edited my question to add that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to combine static resolution given by generic with runtime decisions, and this is not possible.

You can simply overload `f` for both `Float` and `Double` to obtain what you need:

```
func f(seq ls: [Float]) -> Float {
    return sf(ls) // 1. where sf: Float -> Void
}

func f(seq ls: [Double]) -> Double {
    return df(ls) // 2. where df : Double -> Void
}
```

However, if you want `RealType` to be a generic placeholder that you can use over other types than `Float` or, `Double`, then you can do something like this:

```
protocol RealType {
    static func processArray(v: [Self]) -> Self
}

extension Float: RealType {
    static func processArray(v: [Float]) -> Float {
        return sf(v)
    }
}

extension Double: RealType {
    static func processArray(v: [Double]) -> Double {
        return df(v)
    }
}

func sf(v: [Float]) -> Float{
    return 0
}

func  df(v: [Double]) -> Double {
    return 0
}

func f<T: RealType>(seq ls: [T]) -> T {
    return T.processArray(ls)
}
```

This will give you both type safety, which is one of Swift's main advantages, and scalability as whenever you need to add support for `f` over another type, you need to only declare that type as conforming to `RealType`, and implement the `processArray` method.

Comment: Thanks @Cristik. I was looking for a concise solution using Type to decide which branch to execute at runtime. I thought that a static analysis pass (using abstract interpretation) could allows this code since being in the if branch imply that the condition expression was evaluated to true. 
Seem that this is impossible. If so, gonna validate your answer.